# clickonce installer is not taking updates directly when application starts

Tags: clickonce

I made a clickonce installer for my application. I wanted that it should take updates automatically as soon as the application starts. Ergo, I checked the "Application should check for updates" checkbox in updates tab. I created a folder in my local machine by the name of updates in C:. Also i changed the update location to the URL where i upload my updated application on ftp. I included only those dll files in the Application files tab that i had changed and updated. All these updated files went into the C:\updates folder. Now i uploaded this folder on the FTP in the updates folder and the URL was http://www.abcserver.com/projects/abc/test_folder/updates/.
Now when i run my application it is not asking me for the updates but it runs the application directly. Please tell what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty obvious that its not picking up the changes you have made , you should probably check that the [YourAppName].Application has changed on the upload as this is what that framework uses to initially check if a change has been made , If you dont want to do this , you might want to have a look at [WyBuild](http://wyday.com/wybuild/) as its a much nicer app updating framework

Comment: yeah the .aaplication file is changed still no updates when i run the project